# How to execute a Oracle Procedure only once after 7 days of executing another procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am building a Oracle Apex application and my requirement is to call a procedure after 7 days of executing of another procedure. I am not sure whether scheduling will work here or not.

Detail

My application is a Quiz application and I am generating a new quiz every Monday. I want after 7 days it should call another procedure which ends the quiz. So I wanted to execute my result generation procedure after 7 days of my quiz generation procedure.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can use DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS to schedule jobs in oracle. These jobs can in-turn call a procedure.